# Finding ratio of three variables to another three variables using vectors

Tags: vectors

> If $l^2+m^2+n^2=125,\:a^2+b^2+c^2=5$ $and\:al+bm+cn=25$ where a, b, c, l, m, n $\in \mathbb{R}$ then the value of $\:\frac{lmn}{abc}=\mu$ where the sum of digits of $\mu$ is

This question was given under the chapter vectors, I think we need to assume a, b, c and l, m, n are perpendicular to each. I thought of doing this after assuming the above things

$\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}+\overrightarrow{c}=√5$, then squared the whole thing.
Since I assumed a, b and c were perpendicular to each other the square would be $a^2+b^2+c^2=5$, similarly for l, m and c.

But I don't think so this is going to actually get me anywhere with this problem, this was just an attempt I made trying to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two vectors,$\ \vec p=\ell \hat i+m\hat j+n\hat k$ and $\vec q=a\hat i+b\hat j+c\hat k$. Then, the given data can be translated as: $$|\vec p|^2=125\implies |\vec p|=5\sqrt5,$$$$|\vec q|^2=5\implies |\vec q|=\sqrt5.$$ and that $$\vec p\cdot\vec q=25\implies |\vec p||\vec q|\cos\theta=25$$ where $\theta$ is the smaller angle between the two vectors. This gives $$\cos\theta=1\implies\theta=0^{\circ},$$ i.e. the two vectors $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ are PARALLEL, not perpendicular. Thus, we must have, $\vec p=\lambda\vec q$ for some real $\lambda$ and so $|\vec p|=\lambda|\vec q|\implies\lambda=5$. Thus, $$\ell=5a, m=5b, n=5c$$ so $\dfrac{lmn}{abc}=125$ and sum of digits is $8$.